# Wordpress theme keeps mobile browser zoomed in

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile, browser, themes

So, I created a child theme for an HTML5 blank boilerplate theme. Well, when I go onto the site with my mobile phone, the site is super zoomed in and it does not allow you to zoom out. I am sure it's somewhere in the functions file, if someone can help me find it I would greatly appreciate it!

The site is: www.allcementwork.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't zoom in or out is because of this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0;">
```

You're setting the maximum scale to 1 and user-scalable to 0, which means the user can't pinch to zoom in/out. Remove this and it should work as intended.